# subview load from xib,reload view frame, but viewsubviews not change frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.buttonSubView=(EventbuttonsView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActionHeadView" owner:nil options:nil][1];

    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonSubView];

    [self.taskStatusRobView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.left.equalTo(self.view);
        make.right.equalTo(self.view);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-60);
        make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
        make.height.equalTo(@60);
    }];

    [self.buttonSubView layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

buttonSubView is a customview, It's subviews use autolayout ,
when  i call 
`[self.buttonSubView layoutIfNeeded]` ,but subviews donot update frame? why? in xib i use update frame, it is ok.but run in iPhone,cannot work?

Comment: You need to express by constraints how `buttonSubView` should be placed inside `self.view`

Comment: i write this，       `[white makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.top).offset(padding);
        make.left.equalTo(self.left).offset(padding);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.bottom).offset(-padding);
        make.width.equalTo(redView.width);
    }]; `  i donot know  Write the [self.buttonSubView layoutIfNeeded] in where ？

Comment: I cannot understand anything from your comment.

Comment: i write constraints express by constraints how buttonSubView should be placed inside self.view，but  buttonSubView’s subviews layout donot work， so  how should i  do

Comment: Can't see that in your code ? Are you also calling `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` ?

Comment: `- (NSArray *)mas_makeConstraints:(void(^)(MASConstraintMaker *))block {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    MASConstraintMaker *constraintMaker = [[MASConstraintMaker alloc] initWithView:self];
    block(constraintMaker);
    return [constraintMaker install];
}`

Answer (score 2):

You should call the `layoutIfNeeded` method on self.view instead of self.buttonSubView.
 Hope this help.

Comment: little bit strange! I think changing a frame of a super view should change other subviews frame automatically if autolayout is active on that view. but isn't. in my case I change my custom views frame from code and call layoutIfNeeded. It didn't work, but when I add this method (layoutIfNeeded) in the custom view, it worked! I didn't write any single line code in that method. It can be a bug of XCode I think, but not sure.